# Matching strings with start and end characters

Tags: bash, awk

I just started learning about awk programming and am still getting used to it in the bash terminal. If i were to write an expression to match strings that **start** with **de** and **end** with **ed**, i was wondering how does it go about?

Was thinking of something like:

```
 echo -e "deed\ndeath\ndone\ndeindustrialized" |awk '/^de.ed$/'
```

where i match the start and match the end in the awk command but it doesn't print out anything. I'll appreciate some help.

It should produce:

```
deed
deindustrialized
```

I just started today and would like to know.

Comment: What should the output of `echo "death reed" |awk 'script'` be? How about ``echo "rode for feed " |awk 'script'``? In other words are you trying to match words that start with `de` and end with `ed` or whole lines that do that or lines that just contain de followed be ed or lines that start with de and end with ed or something else? Really THINK about what it is you really want to match and then create sample input/output that not only matches when it should but more importantly (s it's harder to code for) does not match when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awk part should be:

```
... | awk '/^de.*ed$/'
deed
deindustrialized
```

`.` matches any character and `*` means that the preceding item will be matched zero or more times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, I'm having the output deed but not deindustrialized.

Comment: Your file probably has windows line ending, ie. `\r\n` meaning that the last character is actually `\r`. Does this work: `awk '/^de.*ed\r?$/'`

Comment: Would there be any difference depending on the OS I'm using? Currently on the Mac OS bash terminal. I don't have a file with words, just fiddling around with the strings in " " in the command.

Comment: I'm totally clueless what comes to Macs. What if you add `\n` after the word _deindustrialized_, like: `echo -e "deed\ndeath\ndone\ndeindustrialized\n" | ...`

Comment: ahh! I'm terribly sorry :P turns out I missed out deindustrialized while typing in the prompt. How silly. Thanks for it once more. It's alright now.

Answer (score 1):

try with awk:

```
echo -e "deed\ndeath\ndone\ndeindustrialized"  | awk 'NR==1;END{print}'
```

Following is the explanation too on same.

```
awk '
NR==1;      ###Checking the NR(Number of line) value is 1, if yes then print the current line(awk works on method of pattern/action, if a condition is TRUE then do actions, in case of NO action do default action which is print of current line).
END{print}' ###In END section now, so it will print the last line of Input_file.
```

Comment: Cool. But what does NR represents? Would love some explanation too.

Comment: great! would be useful in the future!